# Extracing and assigning values from a text file to variable - Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am having trouble assigning values from text file to 4 variables. The file has four values in each line which are separated by space. I want to assign each value to a different variable.

the data in the items.txt:

```
  344443 toothbrush WW WQ 

  243434 ToothPaste WE WQ

  349343 DentalFloss WS QA
```

This is my code which isnt working.

```
 File itemsSold = new File("items.txt");             

 if (itemsSold.exists()){                               
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(itemsSold);  

   while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {

    Items = inputFile.nextLine();    

    ItemId = inputFile.nextInt();
    ItemName = inputFile.next();

    String itemShlve = inputFile.next();
    String itemcode= inputFile.next();

     System.out.print(ItemId + "\n");
     System.out.print(ItemName);
     System.out.print(itemitemShlve);

  }

   inputFile.close();                         

}
```

Output needed is this, which what I get:
    344443
    toothbrush 
    WW

```
243434
ToothPaste 
WE

349343
DentalFloss
WS
```

A beginner to Java, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your actual question? What's the issue in your code?

Comment: Braj is asking what's your error message, or if there isn't one, what happens and what would you have expected to happen instead.

Comment: Break your problem into smaller problems. First, try to read a line from the file. Then extract values from that line. Repeat it for all the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
      Scanner fScn = new Scanner(new File(“items.txt”));
      String data;

      while( fScn.hasNextLine() ){
           data = fScn.nextLine();

           String[] token = data.split(" ");
           itemId = Integer.parseInt(token[0]);
           itemName= token[1];
           itemShelve = token[2];
           itemCode = token[3];
      }
      fScn.close();
```

1) Use file Scanner to capture data line by line

2) Split the line of data into tokens by white spaces

3) Assign the tokens accordingly into respective variables

4) Close file Scanner

Comment: Not only that it will work, you can even create itemId, itemName and the rest as arrays. This way you can store everything from text file into array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix calls to `nextInt` and `nextLine`. Just use `nextLine` in this case.

Comment: I need nextInt because item Id is an integer.

Comment: No, you don't need it. You can get it in a different way. See e.g. the String.split method.

Answer (score 0):

Use another Scanner for each line.

```
if (itemsSold.exists()){                               
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(itemsSold);  

      while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) { // check for next line
           Items = inputFile.nextLine(); // read next line

           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Items);//create new Scanner for new line 
           ItemId = scanner.nextInt(); // read next int
           ItemName = scanner.next();
           String itemShlve = scanner.next();
           String itemcode= scanner.next();  
           scanner.close();  // don't forget to close the Scanner
           ...
      }
      inputFile.close();
}
```

Note: Follow Java Naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help. If you want fourth value also. Set the value 4 in the SysOut Loop.

```
File file = new File("C:\\items.Txt");
        String[] variable = new String[4];
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            int count;
            String temp = new String();
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                count = 0;
                for(char c : line.toCharArray()) {
                    if(c ==' ') {
                        variable[count] = temp;
                        temp = new String();
                        count++;
                    }
                    else {
                        temp += c;
                    }
                }
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    System.out.println(variable[i]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
br.close()
fr.close();
```